# Cassandra 2.2 - Streaming errors at repair/bootstrap/decommission

Tags: cassandra

We're using Cassandra 2.2.7 and we get strange streaming issues when repairing/bootstrapping/decommissioning some nodes. As an example, I was trying to decommission a fresh bootstrapped node and I immediately got the following errors on the node:

```
ERROR [STREAM-OUT-/54.XX.XXX.XXX] 2016-08-04 17:42:44,051 StreamSession.java:532 - [Stream #d89c1640-5a6a-11e6-9152-91527bf14a77] Streaming error occurred
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.doFlush(BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.java:266) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.flush(BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.java:274) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$OutgoingMessageHandler.sendMessage(ConnectionHandler.java:390) [apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$OutgoingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:361) [apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
INFO  [STREAM-OUT-/54.XX.XXX.XXX] 2016-08-04 17:42:44,102 StreamResultFuture.java:183 - [Stream #d89c1640-5a6a-11e6-9152-91527bf14a77] Session with /54.XX.XXX.XXX is complete
WARN  [STREAM-OUT-/54.XX.XXX.XXX] 2016-08-04 17:42:44,102 StreamResultFuture.java:210 - [Stream #d89c1640-5a6a-11e6-9152-91527bf14a77] Stream failed
ERROR [STREAM-OUT-/54.XX.XXX.XXX] 2016-08-04 17:42:44,103 StreamSession.java:532 - [Stream #d89c1640-5a6a-11e6-9152-91527bf14a77] Streaming error occurred
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.doFlush(BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.java:266) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.flush(BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.java:274) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$OutgoingMessageHandler.sendMessage(ConnectionHandler.java:390) [apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$OutgoingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:369) [apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
ERROR [STREAM-IN-/54.XX.XXX.XXX] 2016-08-04 17:42:44,312 StreamSession.java:532 - [Stream #d89c1640-5a6a-11e6-9152-91527bf14a77] Streaming error occurred
java.lang.RuntimeException: Outgoing stream handler has been closed
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler.sendMessage(ConnectionHandler.java:143) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.receive(StreamSession.java:596) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.messageReceived(StreamSession.java:475) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$IncomingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:293) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
```

On other nodes, here is the errors I get:

```
WARN  [STREAM-IN-/163.XXX.XXX.XX] 2016-08-04 17:42:43,234 CompressedStreamReader.java:121 - [Stream d89c1640-5a6a-11e6-9152-91527bf14a77] Error while reading partition DecoratedKey(7971573768827100217, 39653161643838316130303031333963393436366330303863633031636637346565343435366233373663383633343039633963323039313161336333333034) from stream on ks='KEYSPACE_XXXXXXX' and table='TABLE_XXXXXXXX'.
ERROR [STREAM-IN-/163.XXX.XXX.XX] 2016-08-04 17:42:43,315 StreamSession.java:524 - [Stream #d89c1640-5a6a-11e6-9152-91527bf14a77] Streaming error occurred
java.io.IOException: net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4Exception: Error decoding offset 33063 of input buffer
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor.uncompress(LZ4Compressor.java:92) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.compress.CompressedInputStream.decompress(CompressedInputStream.java:116) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.compress.CompressedInputStream.read(CompressedInputStream.java:94) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:337) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.BytesReadTracker.readUnsignedShort(BytesReadTracker.java:140) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.readShortLength(ByteBufferUtil.java:328) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.readWithShortLength(ByteBufferUtil.java:338) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.AbstractCType$Serializer.deserialize(AbstractCType.java:382) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.AbstractCType$Serializer.deserialize(AbstractCType.java:366) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.OnDiskAtom$Serializer.deserializeFromSSTable(OnDiskAtom.java:75) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.AbstractCell$1.computeNext(AbstractCell.java:52) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.AbstractCell$1.computeNext(AbstractCell.java:46) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143) ~[guava-16.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138) ~[guava-16.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter.appendFromStream(BigTableWriter.java:243) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamReader.writeRow(StreamReader.java:187) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.compress.CompressedStreamReader.read(CompressedStreamReader.java:108) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.IncomingFileMessage$1.deserialize(IncomingFileMessage.java:49) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.IncomingFileMessage$1.deserialize(IncomingFileMessage.java:38) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.deserialize(StreamMessage.java:58) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$IncomingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:261) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_77]
Caused by: net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4Exception: Error decoding offset 33063 of input buffer
    at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4JNIFastDecompressor.decompress(LZ4JNIFastDecompressor.java:39) ~[lz4-1.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor.uncompress(LZ4Compressor.java:87) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
INFO  [STREAM-IN-/163.XXX.XXX.XX] 2016-08-04 17:42:43,317 StreamResultFuture.java:182 - [Stream #d89c1640-5a6a-11e6-9152-91527bf14a77] Session with /163.XXX.XXX.XX is complete
WARN  [STREAM-IN-/163.XXX.XXX.XX] 2016-08-04 17:42:43,317 StreamResultFuture.java:209 - [Stream #d89c1640-5a6a-11e6-9152-91527bf14a77] Stream failed
WARN  [Thread-1988] 2016-08-04 17:42:43,319 CompressedInputStream.java:179 - Error while reading compressed input stream.
java.nio.channels.AsynchronousCloseException: null
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:205) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:407) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:59) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:109) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:103) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.compress.CompressedInputStream$Reader.runMayThrow(CompressedInputStream.java:169) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) [apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_77]
```

Sometimes I rather get this one:

```
WARN  [STREAM-IN-/163.XXX.XXX.XX] 2016-08-04 09:00:16,649 CompressedStreamReader.java:121 - [Stream b93dbb30-5a21-11e6-af4d-cf5ff5ded900] Error while reading partition DecoratedKey(-4093657774327370252, 37663734383563316637313338363739613462306435393036663431666566613963336237623534343663366131626238396562393764656262373662373835) from stream on ks='KEYSPACE_XXXXXX' and table='TABLE_XXXXXX'.
WARN  [STREAM-IN-/163.XXX.XXX.XX] 2016-08-04 09:00:17,720 StreamSession.java:655 - [Stream #b93dbb30-5a21-11e6-af4d-cf5ff5ded900] Retrying for following error
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough bytes. Offset: 39. Length: 13113. Buffer size: 54
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.AbstractCType.checkRemaining(AbstractCType.java:362) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.AbstractCompoundCellNameType.fromByteBuffer(AbstractCompoundCellNameType.java:98) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.AbstractCType$Serializer.deserialize(AbstractCType.java:382) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.AbstractCType$Serializer.deserialize(AbstractCType.java:366) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.OnDiskAtom$Serializer.deserializeFromSSTable(OnDiskAtom.java:75) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.AbstractCell$1.computeNext(AbstractCell.java:52) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.AbstractCell$1.computeNext(AbstractCell.java:46) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143) ~[guava-16.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138) ~[guava-16.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter.appendFromStream(BigTableWriter.java:243) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamReader.writeRow(StreamReader.java:187) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.compress.CompressedStreamReader.read(CompressedStreamReader.java:108) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.IncomingFileMessage$1.deserialize(IncomingFileMessage.java:49) [apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.IncomingFileMessage$1.deserialize(IncomingFileMessage.java:38) [apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.deserialize(StreamMessage.java:58) [apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$IncomingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:287) [apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
```

What could be the cause? I don't think it is a network issue because this "not enough bytes" error appeared immediately on all nodes when launching the decommission command whereas I can "scp" for hours between nodes without any problem.

Even a repair is crashing with the same errors, so we're stuck with an "unstable" cluster.

Comment: Logs tells there are 2 different versions of cassandra (2.2.5 and 2.2.7) and JVM (1.8.77 and 1.8.101). While it is possible to do that, you should stick to the same version to limit problems to one specific version.

Comment: Could you clarify if you do a decommission while a repair or any activity is in progress on the node ?

Comment: I'm now 100% in 2.2.7 and after wiping the problematic node, full repair has completed!

Comment: Could you detail the root cause and what you did in an answer to provide support for future use ? thanks

Comment: I would like to do so but I don't know the root cause. I had attached disks but that is fine on other nodes, network was okay. I don't think the version difference can do such damage but I can't be sure, sorry

Answer (score 1):

You should really look to Cassandra's JIRA, it is a good source of information for strange messages or behaviour.
The last strace seems to be related to [this tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10961) for instance

Comment: well, bad example, this bug was fixed in version 2.2.5

Comment: yeah, already found it but I'm in 2.2.7 and this bug is fixed